# What can I do during install of ubuntu server 18.04.5 to take all that I allocate to it in the VM it resides in?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, disk-management

How can I get ubuntu to use use all the disk space that I allocate in my VM?  Is there something I am missing during my install of ubuntu?  When I created my VM I designated 250GB of disk space before I installed ubuntu! However, ubuntu only took up have 123G. What can I do during install of ubuntu to take all that I allocate to it in the VM it resides in?

```
 df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               966M     0  966M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              200M  680K  199M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  123G  3.7G  113G   4% /
tmpfs                              997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2                          976M   78M  832M   9% /boot
tmpfs                              200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

```
 lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                        11:0    1   945M  0 rom
vda                       252:0    0   250G  0 disk
├─vda1                    252:1    0     1M  0 part
├─vda2                    252:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0   249G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 124.5G  0 lvm  /
```

```
 pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/vda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <249.00g <124.50g
```

```
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <249.00g <124.50g
```

```
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 124.50g
```

```
vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <249.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              63743
  Alloc PE / Size       31872 / 124.50 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       31871 / <124.50 GiB
  VG UUID               UCkda3-Ujun-O43Z-MJh2-JkmG-YnY2-VDVNW8
```

All running on a Qnap TS-453D,64-bit x86, Intel® Celeron® J4125 quad-core 2.0 GHz processor, 8GB Mem. Using VirtualizationStation 3 VM, 6TB Disk Space Raid 5.

Comment: It worked much better 2nd time around.with newer install.  This time I played around with the disk space section and did NOT quickly take the default that ubuntu placed in the lvm.

Comment: I played around with all my allocation until the lvm had the exact amount (all) the memory in lvm.  It also helps to understand what the lvm is by simply searching for lvm in this forum and taking your time to READ.  Unfortunately I like to "tinker" until I get it right then sometimes find myself scrounging through the garbage can to read the instructions guide. Like I've said... I'm 74 and still open to learning.

Comment: I hope these comments will help someone else in this useful forum!